# For incoming call, the Phone app does not launch to cover entire screen

Tags: calls, 9.0-pie

In case of an incoming call, the Phone app does not launch to cover the entire screen.  Instead, two buttons are displayed at the top portion of the screen, Reject (red) and Answer (green), as shown below:

[image]

How can I get back the usual behavior for the Phone app where it covers the entire screen on an incoming call, such that a single button is displayed which can be swiped to answer or reject the call?

I am running Android 9.0 on a General Mobile GM 8 device.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is because of Android 9.0 Pie, but based on my experience with Nexus 5 on Android 7.1 Nougat, the Google Phone app will show full-screen activity if it's on idle, but show actionable [heads-up notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#Heads-up) on certain situations.

Comment: Also grant **Display over other apps** permission.

Comment: @AndrewT. You're right, I checked, and if the screen is dark, the full UI pops up.  If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept.  Thank you so much.